# background для SVG

Tags: css3, html5, svg, svg-animation

Есть задача в SVG, - нужно добавить `background`, точнее фотографию. Максимально, что смог нагуглить это - создать маску, но проблема в том, что размеры SVG сильно изменяются. Все попытки вернуть первоначальный размер, не к чему не привели.

Возможно есть другие решения для этой задачи?

[image: оригинал вверху]

Оригинальный размер:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1921.339" height="566.951" viewBox="0 0 1921.339 566.951">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1 {
                    fill: #4095c7;
                    }
        </style>
    </defs>
<path id="Path_27" data-name="Path 27" class="cls-1" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"/></svg>
```

SVG c маской:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1921.339" height="566.951" viewBox="0 0 1921.339 566.951">
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="566.951">
          <path width="1921.339" height="566.951" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs>
 <image x="-50" y="-40" width="1921" height="566" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```

[Ссылка на код в Codepen](https://codepen.io/AndrewKo4/pen/XWWzENp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это ошибка:

> `<path width="1921.339" height="566.951"`

У `path` никогда не указывают ширину и высоту.

---

---

Ваша фотография  имеет размер - `1920 x 1200 px`

Если хотите, чтобы она была помещена в SVG без искажений пропорций необходимо задать такие же размеры viewBox, как и у фото `viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"`

При таком варианте размеры волны, которая выступает в роли маски, и фото будут совпадать.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="566.951">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
          <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```

*Обратите внимание, - я добавил прямоугольник в маску*

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
```

- Если нужно, чтобы был виден немного фон замените чёрный цвет на более
  светлый, например -  `red`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="566.951">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
          <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```

- Допустим вам нужно наоборот, чтобы  вырез в форме волны был не
  закрашен, а фон остался, как есть.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
          <path d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:black;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```

### Анимация фона

Для анимации фона добавляем команду перемещения картинки вверх, вниз

```
<animate attributeName="y" dur="10s" values="0;150;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
          <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)"> 
  <animate attributeName="y" dur="10s" values="0;150;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </image>  
</svg>
```

Связанная тема: [Изменение background для SVG c однотоного на изображение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1041028/28748)

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно сместить фон по оси y ? Например  <image x="0" y="-40" />, можно ли это  сделать с помощью анимации? И возможно ли сделать что бы изначально волна была например синего цвета , а потом появлялось изображение?
Спасибо вам за ваш ответ! Очень помогли

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin Фон можно сместить по верртикали,  изменяя `y`  `<image x="0" y="-100"` Так будет на 100px вверх  Примите ответ, сейчас добавлю анимацию смещения фона. А вот насчет второго вопроса (синий цвет фолны), то его не было изначально, поэтому задайте второй вопрос, там ответ будет намного сложнее

Comment: @AndrewKozhemyakin пример анимации фона добавлен. Жду Отдельного, вновь оформленного вопроса по анимации синей полосы с дальнейшим появлением изображения

Comment: Спасибо, вам! Вопрос в процессе создания

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin  Да не за что :) Спасибо вам за интересный и хорошо оформленный вопрос с кодом. Подожду, если что отвечу завтра с утра

Comment: @Alexander__TT есть еще вопрос: можно ли эту SVG использовать как background в css ?[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051282/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-background-svg-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5]

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin я видел ваш вопрос, попробовал сделать, сразу не получилось. Видимо по причине, что внутри файла идет вызов другого изображения и это, как-то мешает использовать в качестве background/ Как найду время, попробую разобраться с этой проблемой

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin Да не за что :), заглядывайте почаще Проблема, вернее нюанс и для меня в новинку. будет интересно порешать