# Изменение background для SVG c однотоного на изображение

Tags: html, css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Как изменить фон для SVG? Изначально фон синего цвета спустя несколько секунд меняется на изображение.

[image: изменение фона для svg]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
          <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда добавляйте код в вопрос. Вопрос только с одними картинками обычно закрывают, так как он не может быть найден другими участниками при поиске аналогичных вопросов.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT хотел исправить , но вы уже отредактировали, прощу прощение

Comment: @MoloF а как сейчас, изменилось?

Comment: @MoloF сейчас синего цвета вместо картинки нет ,а он должен загружаться первым, а потом меняться на картинку

Comment: @AndrewKozhemyakin вы в вопросе указали что у вас сначала показывается фон самого объекта, а потом подгружается картинка и заменяется, у меня с этим всё нормально и мгновенно без фона картинка встает, с чем именно у вас проблемы? Быть может я не так понял

Comment: @MoloF Прощу прощение, это я неправильно написал. Есть страница , на ней "волна"  имеет цвет фона  - синий, через 5 секунд начинается анимация и вместо синего цвета появляется картинка. Прикрепленный код предназначен для второго состояния

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin развил тему до [рекламного баннера с бегущей строкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1041359/28748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<style>
 .container {
 width:2496;
 height:1560;
 }
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
   <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  

 

 <!-- Синияя волна -->
   <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:#5B70CE; opacity:1;"> 
   
  <!-- Анимация исчезновения синей волны --> 
   <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="4s" begin="1s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
</svg> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно под одной фигурой нарисовать другую, верхнюю показать с задержкой, сделать паузу можно за счет последовательности css анимаций, первая пустая, нужна чтобы сработал delay от второй:

```css
image {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: wait, 1s ease-out 2s op forwards;
}

@keyframes wait {
    from { opacity: 0 }
    to { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes op {
  from { opacity: 0 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
          <path width="1921.339" height="566.951" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" mask="url(#cat)" fill="steelblue"></rect>  
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```