# Создание баннера с бегущей строкой по криволинейному пути

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

Данный вопрос инспирирован топиком :[Изменение background для SVG c однотоного на изображение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1041028/28748)

Появление широкой синей волны поверх фона наталкивает на мысль, что на полосе должен быть, какой-то текст

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  >
 <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
   <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
<g mask="url(#cat)">
<image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"  />  
     
          <path d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:#5B70CE;" opacity="0.4"/>
 </g>
 
    
  <text x="0" y="800" font-size="60px" fill="#8FAFC1" dominant-baseline="baseline" >
     При покупке  авто 
  <tspan fill="red" font-weight="900"> 2019 г.</tspan> получите скидку - 
   <tspan fill="yellowgreen" font-weight="900"> 1000$</tspan> - плюс зимнюю резину, коврики в подарок 
   
 </text> 
 
  
</svg>
```

Который должен быть симметрично расположен внутри этой волны.

Как это сделать?

Как его анимировать?

Comment: Посмотрите на измененный второй вариант решения [Dark theme](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1041427/28748) на мой взгляд будет интересно

Answer (score 9):

Движение текста вдоль криволинейного пути реализуется только в SVG с помощью команды [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/animateMotion)

```
<animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
```

Чтобы заставить эту команду работать необходимо  получить, вычислить  `path`

**Техника получения криволинейного path:**

- Загружаем SVG файл в векторный редактор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. С помощью инструмента - `Рисовать кривые Безье`, на рисунке красная стрелка **1**  добавляем узловые точки
2. Выбираем на верхней панели (2) `сделать выделенные узлы автоматически сглаженными`
3. Двигая рычаги управления узловых точек добиваемся нужной формы кривой
4. Сохраняем файл и забираем из него `Path` (красная кривая на рисунке)

**Текст вдоль криволинейного path:**

```css
.blue_wave {
 fill:#5B70CE;
 filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 15px  skyblue);
 opacity:1;
 }
 .txt1 {
 font-size:60px;
 fill:#F9E20F;
 dominant-baseline:baseline;
 filter: drop-shadow(4px 14px 5px  black);
 }
 #pathText {
 fill:none;
 stroke:none;
 
 
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  >
    <defs> 
      
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
         <path class="path_Mask" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;"/>
    </mask>  
    
   </defs> 
<g mask="url(#cat)">
<image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"  />  
          <!-- Синяя волна -->
          <path class="blue_wave" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z"transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"  >
              
          </path>
    </g>   
          <!-- Криволинейная трасса движения текста -->
    <path id="pathText" d="m15 480.5c0 0 94.7 2.4 133.6-20.3 109.9-64 139.4-222.6 235.9-300 61.9-49.7 161-49.1 219.1-4.9 111.7 85.1 124.3 231.8 227.6 306 35.6 25.6 135.6 44.5 197 20.3 133.8-52.5 160.2-251.5 284.1-324.3 104.1-61.1 181.4-48.9 248.1 0 62.7 46 124.5 260.1 212.4 292.9 82.4 30.7 123.8 11 123.8 11" />
    
 <text class="txt1" x="0" y="0"  >
   <textPath xlink:href="#pathText" startOffset="0%">  
    При покупке  автомобиля 
     <tspan fill="red" font-weight="900"> 2019 г.</tspan> получаете скидку - 
      <tspan fill="yellowgreen" font-weight="900"> 1000$</tspan> -  зимнюю резину и коврики в подарок  
      
    </textPath>  
</text>     
 
  
</svg>
```

**Анимация движения текста**

```
<animate id="an_text" begin="1s" dur="20s" repeatCount="1"  
  attributeName="startOffset" values="100%;1%;1%;50%;50%;100%"/>
```

```css
.blue_wave {
 fill:#5B70CE;
 filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 15px  skyblue);
 opacity:0;
 }
 .txt1 {
 font-size:60px;
 fill:#F9E20F;
 dominant-baseline:baseline;
 filter: drop-shadow(4px 14px 5px  black);
 }
 #pathText {
 fill:none;
 stroke:none;
 
 
 
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  >
    <defs> 
      
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
         <path class="path_Mask" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;"/>
    </mask>  
     <!-- Подсветка фар -->
  <path id="headlamp" d="m462.9 580.7c0 0-14.8 12-10.3 36.2 3.4 18.5 16.6 40.1 43.6 41.1 31 1.1 46.1-25.4 48.2-38 3.6-22.6-8.7-36.9-8.7-36.9" >
      
  </path>   
   </defs> 
<g mask="url(#cat)">
<image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"  />  
          <!-- Синяя волна -->
          <path class="blue_wave" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z"transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"  >
              <animate id="an_opacity" attributeName="opacity" begin="0.5s;an_text.end+2s" dur="1.5s" values="0;1" fill="freeze" />
          </path>
    </g>   
          <!-- Криволинейная трасса движения текста -->
    <path id="pathText" d="m15 480.5c0 0 94.7 2.4 133.6-20.3 109.9-64 139.4-222.6 235.9-300 61.9-49.7 161-49.1 219.1-4.9 111.7 85.1 124.3 231.8 227.6 306 35.6 25.6 135.6 44.5 197 20.3 133.8-52.5 160.2-251.5 284.1-324.3 104.1-61.1 181.4-48.9 248.1 0 62.7 46 124.5 260.1 212.4 292.9 82.4 30.7 123.8 11 123.8 11" />
    
 <text class="txt1" x="0" y="0"  >
   <textPath xlink:href="#pathText" startOffset="100%">  
    При покупке  авто 
     <tspan fill="red" font-weight="900"> 2019 г.</tspan> получите скидку - 
      <tspan fill="yellowgreen" font-weight="900"> 1000$</tspan> - плюс зимнюю резину, коврики в подарок  
      <!-- Анимация движения текста вдоль трассы-->
      <animate id="an_text" begin="1s" dur="20s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="startOffset" values="100%;1%;1%;50%;50%;100%"/> 
    </textPath>  
</text>     
  
</svg>
```

**Анимация мигания подсветкой фар**

Анимация реализуется с помощью изменения ширины строки и покраской в желтый цвет

Для получения строки обводки фар снова используем векторный редактор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишем формулу анимации для этой строки:

```
 <!-- Анимация моргания блока подсветки фар -->
   <animate id="an_lamp" xlink:href="#gr1" attributeName="stroke-width" begin="an_opacity.end" values="1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" calcMode="discrete" />
```

**Собираем всё вместе:**

Чтобы не пропустить нюансы анимации, откройте полноэранный режим.

*Анимация начнется после клика по изображению*

```css
.blue_wave {
 fill:#5B70CE;
 filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 15px  skyblue);
 opacity:0;
 }
 .txt1 {
 font-size:60px;
 fill:#F9E20F;
 dominant-baseline:baseline;
 filter: drop-shadow(4px 14px 5px  black);
 }
 #pathText {
 fill:none;
 stroke:none;
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  >
    <defs> 
      
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
         <path class="path_Mask" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;"/>
    </mask>  
     <!-- Подсветка фар -->
  <path id="headlamp" d="m462.9 580.7c0 0-14.8 12-10.3 36.2 3.4 18.5 16.6 40.1 43.6 41.1 31 1.1 46.1-25.4 48.2-38 3.6-22.6-8.7-36.9-8.7-36.9" >
      
  </path>   
   </defs> 
<g mask="url(#cat)">
<image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"  />  
          <!-- Синяя волна -->
          <path class="blue_wave" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z"transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"  >
             <!-- Анимация прозрачности синей волны -->
             <animate id="an_opacity"
        attributeName="opacity"
        begin="svg1.click;an_text.end+2s"
        dur="1.5s"
        values="0;0.2"
        fill="freeze" />
          </path>
    </g>   
          <!-- Криволинейная трасса движения текста -->
    <path id="pathText" d="m15 480.5c0 0 94.7 2.4 133.6-20.3 109.9-64 139.4-222.6 235.9-300 61.9-49.7 161-49.1 219.1-4.9 111.7 85.1 124.3 231.8 227.6 306 35.6 25.6 135.6 44.5 197 20.3 133.8-52.5 160.2-251.5 284.1-324.3 104.1-61.1 181.4-48.9 248.1 0 62.7 46 124.5 260.1 212.4 292.9 82.4 30.7 123.8 11 123.8 11" />
    
 <text class="txt1" x="0" y="0"  >
   <textPath xlink:href="#pathText" startOffset="100%">  
    При покупке  авто 
     <tspan fill="red" font-weight="900"> 2019 г.</tspan> получите скидку - 
      <tspan fill="yellowgreen" font-weight="900"> 1000$</tspan> - плюс зимнюю резину, коврики в подарок  
      <!-- Анимация движения текста вдоль трассы-->
      <animate id="an_text"
    begin="an_lamp.end"
    dur="20s"
    repeatCount="1"
    attributeName="startOffset"
    values="100%;1%;1%;50%;50%;100%"/> 
    </textPath>  
</text>     
  
    <!-- Блок подсветки фар -->
 <g id="gr1" fill="none" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" > 
  <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(0, 0)"  /> 
  <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(120, 0)"  /> 
    <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(824, 0)"  />
      <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(943, 0)"  />
 </g> 
    <!-- Анимация моргания блока подсветки фар -->
   <animate id="an_lamp"
   xlink:href="#gr1"
   attributeName="stroke-width"
   begin="an_opacity.end"
   values="1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1"
   dur="2s"
   repeatCount="1"
   calcMode="discrete" />
 
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Dark theme

Вариант с темной палитрой цветов.
Добавлены дополнительные эффекты анимации и решения.

```css
.dark_wave {
 fill:#323338;
 stroke:black;
 filter: url(#dropshadow);
 opacity:0;
 }
 .txt1 {
 font-size:60px;
 fill:#C5CDCD;
 stroke:none;
 dominant-baseline:baseline;
 filter: url(#dropshadow);
 }
 #pathText {
 fill:none;
 stroke:none;
 
 }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  >
 <defs> 
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="8" dy="8" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
   <path class="path_Mask" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;"/>
    </mask>  
  <!-- Подсветка фар -->
  <path id="headlamp" d="m462.9 580.7c0 0-14.8 12-10.3 36.2 3.4 18.5 16.6 40.1 43.6 41.1 31 1.1 46.1-25.4 48.2-38 3.6-22.6-8.7-36.9-8.7-36.9" >
     
  </path> 
   </defs> 
<g mask="url(#cat)">
<image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"  />  
          <!-- Тёмная волна -->
          <path class="dark_wave" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z"transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"  >
       <!-- Анимация прозрачности темной волны -->
    <animate id="an_opacity" attributeName="opacity" begin="svg1.click;an_text.end+2s" dur="1.5s" values="0;0.8" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
 </g>   
       <!-- Криволинейная трасса движения текста -->
 <path id="pathText" d="m15 480.5c0 0 94.7 2.4 133.6-20.3 109.9-64 139.4-222.6 235.9-300 61.9-49.7 161-49.1 219.1-4.9 111.7 85.1 124.3 231.8 227.6 306 35.6 25.6 135.6 44.5 197 20.3 133.8-52.5 160.2-251.5 284.1-324.3 104.1-61.1 181.4-48.9 248.1 0 62.7 46 124.5 260.1 212.4 292.9 82.4 30.7 123.8 11 123.8 11" />
    
 <text class="txt1" x="0" y="0"  >
   <textPath xlink:href="#pathText" startOffset="100%">  
    При покупке  авто 
  <tspan fill="gold" font-weight="900"> 2019 г.</tspan> получите скидку - 
   <tspan fill="yellowgreen" font-weight="900"> 1000$</tspan> - плюс зимнюю резину, коврики в подарок  
     <!-- Анимация движения текста вдоль трассы-->
   <animate id="an_text" begin="an_lamp.end" dur="20s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="startOffset" values="100%;1%;1%;50%;50%;100%"/> 
    </textPath>  
</text>  
  
    <!-- Блок подсветки фар -->
 <g id="gr1" fill="none" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" > 
  <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(0, 0)"  /> 
  <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(120, 0)"  /> 
    <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(824, 0)"  />
   <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(943, 0)"  />
 </g> 
    <!-- Анимация моргания блока подсветки фар -->
   <animate id="an_lamp" xlink:href="#gr1" attributeName="stroke-width" begin="an_opacity.end" values="1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" calcMode="discrete" />
 
  
</svg>
```

**Вариант с комплексной анимацией автомобиля: мягкой покачивание, мигание фарами, бегущая строка**

```css
.dark_wave {
 fill:#323338;
 stroke:black;
 filter: url(#dropshadow);
 opacity:0;
 }
 .txt1 {
 font-size:60px;
 fill:#C5CDCD;
 stroke:none;
 dominant-baseline:baseline;
 filter: url(#dropshadow);
 }
 #pathText {
 fill:none;
 stroke:none;
 
 }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  >
 <defs> 
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1"/> 
      <feOffset dx="8" dy="8" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
      <mask id="cat" width="1920" height="1200">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <!-- path в форме волны вырезает из картинки фона часть изображения -->         
   <path class="path_Mask" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;"/>
    </mask>  
  <!-- Подсветка фар -->
  <path id="headlamp" d="m462.9 580.7c0 0-14.8 12-10.3 36.2 3.4 18.5 16.6 40.1 43.6 41.1 31 1.1 46.1-25.4 48.2-38 3.6-22.6-8.7-36.9-8.7-36.9" >
     
  </path> 
   </defs>  
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <g >
<g mask="url(#cat)">
<image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1bDl.jpg"  />  
          <!-- Тёмная волна -->
          <path class="dark_wave" d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z"transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"  >
       <!-- Анимация прозрачности темной волны -->
    <animate id="an_opacity" attributeName="opacity" begin="svg1.click;an_text.end+2s" dur="1.5s" values="0;0.8" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
 </g>   
       <!-- Криволинейная трасса движения текста -->
 <path id="pathText" d="m15 480.5c0 0 94.7 2.4 133.6-20.3 109.9-64 139.4-222.6 235.9-300 61.9-49.7 161-49.1 219.1-4.9 111.7 85.1 124.3 231.8 227.6 306 35.6 25.6 135.6 44.5 197 20.3 133.8-52.5 160.2-251.5 284.1-324.3 104.1-61.1 181.4-48.9 248.1 0 62.7 46 124.5 260.1 212.4 292.9 82.4 30.7 123.8 11 123.8 11" />
    
 <text class="txt1" x="0" y="0"  >
   <textPath xlink:href="#pathText" startOffset="100%">  
    При покупке  авто 
  <tspan fill="gold" font-weight="900"> 2019 г.</tspan> получите скидку - 
   <tspan fill="yellowgreen" font-weight="900"> 1000$</tspan> - плюс зимнюю резину, коврики в подарок  
     <!-- Анимация движения текста вдоль трассы-->
   <animate id="an_text" begin="an_lamp.end" dur="20s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="startOffset" values="100%;1%;1%;50%;50%;100%"/> 
    </textPath>  
</text>  
  
    <!-- Блок подсветки фар -->
 <g id="gr1" fill="none" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" > 
  <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(0, 0)"  /> 
  <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(120, 0)"  /> 
    <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(824, 0)"  />
   <use  xlink:href="#headlamp" transform="translate(943, 0)"  />
 </g> 
    <!-- Анимация моргания блока подсветки фар -->
   <animate id="an_lamp" xlink:href="#gr1" attributeName="stroke-width" begin="an_opacity.end" values="1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1;12;1;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" calcMode="discrete" /> 
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" 
                type="skewY" values="1;-1.4;1" 
                begin="an_text.begin+4s" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="2"/>
 </g>
  
</svg>
```