# Анимация блока из раскладывающихся плиток

Tags: javascript, css, html5, scss, jsx

Учусь работать с анимациями в css3 и возникла мысль, реализовать следующее решение.

[image: Смотрим приложенный скриншот]

Есть кнопка данного вида (первое изображение на скриншоте).
 Необходимо, чтобы при переходе на страницу данная кнопка разворачивалась, как на втором изображении на скриншоте.
 То есть, сперва появляется первая секция (нумерация на втором изображении), затем, как будто перелистывается лист и появляется вторая секция, потом снова перелистывание только вниз и проявляется третья секция, перелистывание влево и проявляется четвёртая секция, итогом становится полная кнопка.
 Реально ли такое реализовать, и если да, то как? 
 Готовых или похожих примеров найти не получилось.
 Буду очень благодарен за подсказки или хотя бы схематичное решение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.c-weird-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem; height: 10rem;
  perspective: 600px; }

  .c-weird-btn .o-tile {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%; height: 50%; 
    background: no-repeat radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, #0dd, #0dd 33%, transparent 33%) #a7e; }

  .c-weird-btn .o-tile:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform-origin: right center;
    animation: wb-t-tr 0.5s ease-out 0.1s forwards; }
  .c-weird-btn .o-tile:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform-origin: left center;
    animation: wb-t-bl 0.5s ease-out 0.9s forwards; }
  .c-weird-btn .o-tile:nth-of-type(4) {
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    animation: wb-t-br 0.5s ease-out 0.5s forwards; }

@keyframes wb-t-tr {
  50%  { filter: brightness(75%); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(180deg); } }
@keyframes wb-t-bl {
  0%   { bottom: 0; right: 0; background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, #0dd, #0dd 33%, transparent 33%); }
  50%  { filter: brightness(75%); }
  100% { bottom: 0; right: 0; background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, #0dd, #0dd 33%, transparent 33%); transform: rotateY(-180deg); } }
@keyframes wb-t-br {
  0%   { right: 0; background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, #0dd, #0dd 33%, transparent 33%); }
  50%  { filter: brightness(75%); }
  100% { right: 0; background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, #0dd, #0dd 33%, transparent 33%); transform: rotateX(-180deg); } }
```

```html
<div class="c-weird-btn">
  <div class="o-tile"></div>
  <div class="o-tile"></div>
  <div class="o-tile"></div>
  <div class="o-tile"></div>
</div>
```

Поместить изображения на тайлы можно не только через `background-image` самого тайла (как в примере), но и добавив каждому из них вложенные элементы лицевой и оборотной сторон. Во втором случае, видимость сторон надо будет переключать в кадрах анимации (на 50%, что соответствует положению "на ребре").

Comment: @yar85 а вы не хотите попробовать себя или уже пробовали, я просто не знаю, - в [само ответах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1041359/28748). Я бы с интересом почитал, да и другие уверен тоже.  Хороших вопросов катастрофически мало.  А у вас чувствуется  потенциал.  Это может быть JS, CSS или что-то другое. Конечно мне более близок SVG, может тоже просто зададите вопрос?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, обязательно попробую, когда встречу интересную задачу в своем внешнем к SO мире :) Подобных задач там в целом маловато (у меня скучная работа с колоссальным техн. долгом), но все же иногда попадаются.

Comment: @yar85 не обязательно ждать и искать, когда попадётся, само приплывёт, можно ведь самому придумать на тему, которую хорошо знаете и желательно не очень сложную реализацию с демонстрацией всех своих возможностей. Секрет успеха, - такого вопроса-ответа, чтобы было понятного на среднем уровне.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ресурсов на придумывание сейчас не хватает, к сожалению. Поэтому максимум что получится, это делиться какими-то текущими решениями, добавляя к ним описание.