# Не отображается background SVG на странице?

Tags: html, css, svg

Пытаюсь использовать SVG в качестве `background-image` для блока, но вместо фона пустой блок.

В чем может быть проблема ?

```css
.svg__svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 525px;
    background-image: url("car.svg");
}
```

```html
<div class="svg__svg"></div>
```

Код SVG

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1921.339 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
      <mask id="cat" width="1921.339" height="566.951">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
          <path  d="M1906.011,483.64c-14.293-.643-25.757-3.117-36.03-7.733-20.5-9.16-41.453-28.267-64.126-58.389-16.568-21.747-32.776-47.944-49.918-75.663-21.375-34.524-43.474-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.382-68.525-97.37-89.916a273.7,273.7,0,0,0-143.63-40.235h-1.042c-40.538,0-78.8,8.161-114.044,24.15-65.254,29.623-108.217,79.946-134.867,115.208-23.8,31.883-43.878,64.266-63.3,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.646,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.909,21.581-33.18,37.165-48.536,46.469-16.441,9.874-31.627,13.99-52.237,14.109-15.441-.048-28.181-2.617-41.028-8.375-20.461-9.16-41.432-28.267-64.083-58.389-16.569-21.747-32.754-47.9-49.919-75.663-21.354-34.477-43.453-70.191-70.379-104.739-31.478-40.021-62.361-68.525-97.348-89.916a273.663,273.663,0,0,0-143.651-40.235c-41.581,0-79.844,8.161-115.066,24.15C329.124,160.739,286.16,211.062,259.51,246.324c-23.821,31.883-43.9,64.266-63.318,95.578-18.844,30.408-36.647,59.1-54.683,81.8-16.93,21.581-33.2,37.165-48.557,46.469-13.421,8.066-26.246,12.111-42.687,13.4L18,486.186V673.917L54.285,672.3c36.157-1.618,70.06-9.494,100.794-23.46,65.253-29.623,108.238-79.97,134.888-115.232,23.8-31.86,43.878-64.242,63.3-95.6,18.866-30.36,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.243-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.483-9.874,31.648-13.967,52.237-14.109,15.462.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.569,21.723,32.776,47.92,49.918,75.639,21.376,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.358,104.739,31.478,40,62.361,68.5,97.37,89.916a273.762,273.762,0,0,0,143.63,40.187c41.581,0,79.844-8.09,115.065-24.079,65.253-29.67,108.217-79.97,134.867-115.255,23.821-31.883,43.878-64.266,63.3-95.579,18.844-30.408,36.647-59.1,54.661-81.778,16.93-21.58,33.222-37.165,48.557-46.492,16.463-9.874,31.627-13.967,52.215-14.109,15.463.071,28.2,2.641,41.049,8.4,20.482,9.137,41.453,28.267,64.1,58.413,16.59,21.723,32.775,47.9,49.94,75.639,21.375,34.477,43.453,70.191,70.379,104.739,31.478,40,62.382,68.5,97.37,89.916,40.3,24.84,87.756,38.569,137.079,39.759l35.6.833V485.187Z" transform="translate(-18 -106.966)"
      style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white; fill:white;"/>
    </mask> 
   </defs> 
 <image x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/ce/35/ccce355cc6f83a3b12ac4e752c795e69.jpg"
 mask="url(#cat)">
 </image>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему SVG, содержащий xlink:href, не отображается как background?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245922/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-svg-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-xlinkhref-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загрузить данный, конкретный файл SVG с помощью `background-image` не удалось. Видимо это происходит из-за того, что внутри используется вызов другого изображения.

Можно конечно преобразовать файл в формат Base64 и тогда удастся загрузка, но какой смысл в этом, так как это будет уже не SVG в полном понимании.

Когда вы загружаете файл, как `background-image`, SVG теряет все свои преимущества перед растровыми изображениями. Он сам представляет в этом случае обыкновенное изображение, у которого можно поменять только ширину, высоту. Становятся невозможной стилизация, как и у растровыx изображений, пропадает интерактивность, анимация.

Если не хочется терять эти преимущества, то остаются только два способа:

### 1. Инлайн загрузка,

то есть непосредственное копирование SVG в HTML страницу.

### 2. Object

```html
<style>
.svg__svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}
</style>
<object id="c1" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/car.svg" width="100%" height="100%" >
  
</object>
<div class="svg__svg">

</div>
```

Но здесь очень много нюансов и опять многое зависит от содержимого SVG файла.

Остаются другие, более простые способы использования изображения, но они аналогичны загрузке в `background`, то есть это будет обычная фоновая картинка.

### `<img>`

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh03t.png">
```

### content

```html
<style>
.svg__svg {
    width: 692px;
    height: 417px;
   content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh03t.png");
  
}

</style>
<div class="svg__svg"></div>
```

**Выбирайте, какой способ вам лучше подойдёт.**

Другие способы загрузки svg в HTML можно посмотреть [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

**UPDATE**

Мне всё таки больше нравится использование SVG по прямому назначению, когда можно стилизовать, анимировать. Посмотрите например пример анимации вашей картинки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1041427/28748

Comment: @Alexandr__TT , спасибо за ваш ответ !

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin Да не за что. Спрашивайте ещё. Всегда рад помочь