# Почему SVG, содержащий xlink:href, не отображается как background?

Tags: css, svg

Нарисовал svg по просьбе, как inline работает хорошо но не отображается если подключить его в css как background....

Переделал кучу раз ..

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" />
      <path d="M0,0 300,0  C300,0 600,300 900,0 L1200,0 1200,600 C1200,600 600,500 0,600z" fill="#fff" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vqvUC-1pNvo/maxresdefault.jpg" width="1200px" height="600px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Почему документ может не работать в css как фон ? Что надо сделать что бы  заработал ?

Comment: Сам по себе svg на фоне очевидно работает, если добавить какую-нибудь простую фигуру вроде rect. А вот почему image на фоне не работает — это уже интересно

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391142

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В спецификации [SVG Integration](https://svgwg.org/specs/integration/) (хоть и черновик, но в браузерах, похоже, давно реализовано) указано, что при использовании SVG-файла в HTML-теге `<img>` или CSS-свойствах (в том числе `background`) этот SVG-файл интерпретируется как *«animated image document»*, и для такого вида интеграции должен применяться *«secure animated processing mode»*, который запрещает не только выполнение скриптов, но и ссылки на любые внешние ресурсы. Поэтому не судьба.

Если отказаться от ссылок и встроить картинку прямо в SVG с помощью Data URI (`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...`), то она отобразится. (Впрочем, это сомнительное решение...)

Comment: я так делал ...не работало ..спасибо я так и думал

Comment: Всё верно. Тоже ковыряю SVG и недавно посещал сей раздел, только по поводу скриптов и интерактивности. Был разочарован.

Comment: @MaximLensky я перед написанием ответа сделал Data URI и у меня заработало. Возможно вы где-то опечатались

Comment: обалдеть просто - ещё раз спасибо